# Table-Valued Functions in ORACLE PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

I am trying to find a simple way to use Oracle's Table-Valued functions, as I am quite new to it.

I found a tutorial online which works. However, it's quite complex if compared to other non-Oracle implementations of Table-Valued functions.

in the tutorial it does something like this:

```
create or replace type t_record as object (
  i number,
  n varchar2(30)
);
```

then, creates the table

```
create or replace type t_table as table of t_record;
```

and finally create the function

```
create or replace function return_table return t_table as
  v_ret   t_table;
begin

 --
 -- Call constructor to create the returned
 -- variable:
 --
    v_ret  := t_table();

 --
 -- Add one record after another to the returned table.
 -- Note: the »table« must be extended before adding
 -- another record:
 --
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(1, 'one'  );
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(2, 'two'  );
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record(3, 'three');

 --
 -- Return the record:
 --
    return v_ret;

end return_table;
/
```

and then we can simply get the function's result using a query call.

```
select * from table(return_table);
```

Is there any simpler, cleaner way to do this, like just writing the query as the function's body and return it without all the initializing and extending and adding ?.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you don't want to use it like a table (e.g. in a JOIN or adding a WHERE clause) then you could use a procedure and return the result through `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT`

Comment: Unfortunately PL/SQL doesn't have anonymous types - you can't have `function f return table of t%rowtype`, you have to specify an existing type. Once it's defined, though, you can reuse it wherever you want. But are you sure a table function is what you need?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I think in my case a view would do the trick. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can create a table :

```
SQL> create table tab(
  i number,
  n varchar2(30)
);
```

and populate :

```
SQL> insert all 
       into tab values(1, 'one')
       into tab values(2, 'two')
       into tab values(3, 'three')
select * from dual;
```

and then populate type object values through an implicit cursor within the function :

```
SQL> create or replace function return_table return t_table as
  v_ret   t_table:= t_table();
begin

 for c in ( select * from tab )
 loop
    v_ret.extend; v_ret(v_ret.count) := t_record( c.i, c.n );
 end loop;

    return v_ret;

end return_table;
/
```

and call :

```
SQL> select * from table(return_table);

I   N
-   -----
1   One 
2   Two
3   Three
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's still a complex way. I am thinking of using view instead, even though they don' take parameters.

Comment: you're welcome @Jalil.Jarjanazy. It's hard to suggest an alternative way. Perhaps `dbms_output.put_line` might be used by writing values explicitly.  Btw, it's interesting that you live in Ankara like me, and working at Nokia like my brother who lives in Antwerp.

Comment: Yes it's an interesting coincidence :)